# Sum numbers in For loop in React

Tags: reactjs

I have got series of data that contains some objects in one array(json file) and it will be shown by fetch() request.As you can see in `{this.renderCountETotal(item)}`I have a `for loop` and I want to sum the numbers in `for loop` but return me `NaN`.

```
   class App extends React.Component{
   constructor(props,context){
    super(props,context);
    this.state={
        data:[],
     }
    }
       .
       .
       .
       .
       .
render() {
  const {data} = this.state;
  const renderInvoicesTotal =data.map((item, i) => {
        return   <span>
                    {this.renderCountETotal(item)}
                 </span>
     })
 return (
     <div>
       {renderInvoicesTotal}
  </div>
   )
  }
renderCountETotal(element){
  let lenInfo=element.byproducts.length
  let valueAdded = 0
  for(let i = 0 ; i < lenInfo ; i++){
    let count= parseInt(element.byproducts[i].count)
    valueAdded += count
   }
    valueAdded = parseInt(valueAdded)
    console.log(valueAdded) ////return NaN ////
    return valueAdded
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('Result'))
```

Comment: what is value of `valueAdded ` before parsing.

Comment: Hi @Kaushik. It is `let valueAdded = 0`

Comment: Not this, after `for loop`

Comment: check for `element.byproducts[i].count` value. I think `element.byproducts[i].count` is not available in all the products. because `parseInt(undefined + number) => NaN`.

Comment: ie; before `valueAdded = parseInt(valueAdded)` line, what is the value of `valueAdded`? could you please put a `console.log(valueAdded)` and check?

Comment: After `for loop` this is `NaN`.

Comment: The result of this part: `for(let i = 0 ; i < lenInfo ; i++){
 let count= parseInt(element.byproducts[i].count);
    console.log(count)
        valueAdded += adultcount;
    console.log(valueAdded)
}`

Comment: I think then the case would be what @MayankShukla has said. Check out the value of  `element.byproducts[i].count` ? is it `undefined` ?

Comment: Is : 383 
383 
109 
492 
NaN

Comment: No it is not `undefined `.

Comment: instead of putting check do this: `parseInt(element.byproducts[i].count || 0);`, and check the result.

Comment: Try adding `let count= element.byproducts[i].count ? parseInt(element.byproducts[i].count) : 0`

Comment: @bita, that means `count` is either not available in all the products or its value is null for any one product.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the rendercountETotal method with this :

```
renderCountETotal(element)
   {
  let valueAdded = 0
  let count = 0
  for(let i = 0 ; i < element.byproducts.length ; i++)
  {
    count= parseInt(element.byproducts[i])
    valueAdded += count
  }
    return valueAdded
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `reduce` function to get aggregate count:-

```
const getCount = element.reduce((x,y) => x + (y.byproducts || 0));
```